# ImportError: No module named version in Astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I currently have an anaconda installation of of Python, which includes astropy and numpy among other useful packages. I recently updated my Astropy individually through pip, by running

```
pip install --upgrade astropy
```

After this silly thing that I probably should not have done (I should have upgrades the entire anaconda package), my pyspeckit package stopped working, claiming it could not find the version.py in astropy.
This is the error I get:

```
   /Users/saracamnasio/Research/code/MC_test.py in <module>()
      5 import utilities as u
      6 import BDdb
----> 7 import pyspeckit
      8 import StringIO
      9 import corner

/Users/saracamnasio/Research/code/pyspeckit/pyspeckit/__init__.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 if not _ASTROPY_SETUP_:
---> 10     from version import version as __version__
     11     import spectrum
     12     import specwarnings

ImportError: No module named version
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall astropy, as well as update anaconda independently but it's not working to fix it. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Comparing your traceback (hurray for IPython & context lines) with the current code on bitbucket, you may want to upgrade pyspeckit as well: your version is definitely not Python 3 compatible, but the current (bitbucket) version is. Since pyspeckit is on pip, `pip install --upgrade pyspeckit` may do it.

Comment: That line in the traceback in pyspeckit should say `from .version`; it's not performing a relative import correctly. It's nothing to do with pip, or even Astropy really.

Answer (score 2):

Evert's comment is most likely the correct answer: just update pyspeckit.  The version you're using is out of date and has some potential inconsistencies in how it does relative imports.

However, what you have uncovered is, if not a bug, definitely not a feature, so it will be removed soon:

https://github.com/pyspeckit/pyspeckit/pull/134

Comment: I had already updated pyspeckit, so that was not the problem. I reverted to python 2, I have the latest version of pyspeckit, and I removed the import version line from pyspeckit.

Comment: There are a few bugs in Baseline still, which I was able to work by messing around with the arguments. Anyhow, this is now fixed. Thank you all!

Comment: @SaraCamnasio could you report the baseline issues on the pyspeckit issue tracker? github.com/pyspeckit/pyspeckit/issues